# Jquery Datatable theme Hide header/footer balk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am trying to remove the header/footer balk of this table

Picture of what I am trying to remove:
[image]

The Jquery code of this table:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false, //Disable search function
     "bJQueryUI": true, //Enable smooth theme
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" //Enable smooth theme
    });
    });
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: please give us your markup. A fiddle would help the most. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: According to the docs, you can just turn those off. http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

Answer (score 17):

I am not able to view the image, But I am assuming that you want only to display the table and remove the search,paging and info features..

Add the following attribute in the dataTable declaration

```
"sDom": 't'
```

Some thing like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false, //Disable search function
     "bJQueryUI": true, //Enable smooth theme
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", //Enable smooth theme
        "sDom": 't'
    });
    });
```

To get Back replace **t** with **lfrtip**

```
"sDom": 'lfrtip'
```

To display some of the features use it as

`"sDom": '<"fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"`**lfr**`>`**t**`<"fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"`**ip**`>'`

> l= Length changing
>
> f= Filtering input
>
> r= pRocessing
>
> t= Table
>
> i= Info
>
> p= Pagination

Have a look at [dataTables sDom Options](http://www.datatables.net/ref#sDom) for more details

Comment: You can also check the example : [DataTables DOM positioning example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

Comment: Just want to point out that the correct option name now is `dom` and not `sDom`. [documentation reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom).

Answer (score 1):

via js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
        "bFilter" : false, 
        "bJQueryUI" : true, 
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers", 
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bInfo": false
    });
});
```

or via css:

```
/* these classes are generated by 'jquery.dataTables.js' */

.dataTables_length, 
.dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_info,
.dataTables_paginate {
    display:none;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y94mT/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Hide the pagination with:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
      "bFilter": false, //Disable search function
      "bJQueryUI": true, //Enable smooth theme
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", //Enable smooth theme
      "bPaginate": false //hide pagination
  });
});
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, just it only adjusts the height of the top bar (Not remove it) and it doesnt do anything to the underbar.

Comment: Then: Maybe remove it via css. Set the header and footer to display:none!

Comment: Yeah but the problem is how would I do that! As far as I know they dont have any special ID assigned..

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jquery but shouldn't you just set `style="display: none;"` or `style="visibility: hidden;"` or remove it with the DOM by using removeChild (normal javascript). And maybe you could use first and last sibling to select header and footer (just a bunch of ideas, sorry to do it this way can't comment yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below! Hope that helps!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
        "bFilter" : false, //Disable search function
        "bJQueryUI" : true, //Enable smooth theme
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers", //Enable smooth theme
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bInfo" : false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `bJQueryUI` to `false`, this will take out the balk part of header and footer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false, //Disable search function
     "bJQueryUI": false, //Enable smooth theme
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" //Enable smooth theme
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('tfoot').remove();

Removes the footer row.  Which is something I was stumped by for some time.

Comment: guess you missing a `.` or a `#` to check if its a class or a id

Answer (score 0):

```
            oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                bJQueryUI: true,
                bFilter: false, 
                bInfo: false,
                bPaginate: false,
                sDom: 't'
            });
```

This will remove search bar, pagination, header and footer.